# ExactTarget Api Interaction/v1/interactions "You do not have access to this object"

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, interaction

I seem to have access to most of the endpoints (all those I have tested) as defined in `GET /interaction/v1/rest`.  I DO NOT have access to `GET /interaction/v1/interactions`.

When attempting to `GET /interaction/v1/interactions` for a list I receive the following:

> {   "message": "You do not have access to this object.",
>   "errorcode": 20000,   "documentation": "" }

My request looks like this:

```
GET /interaction/v1/interactions HTTP/1.1
Host: www.exacttargetapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <My Token>
```

Can anyone provide some insight on why this call is not working for me?

Comment: In the app center make sure that your user has permission to read interactions

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I checked the permissions and just checked them again.  Still no go.

However, creating a NEW App in the App center with the permissions allows me to GET on this endpoint.  The existing App still does not.

Comment: This is right. You can't change permissions once you have created them

Comment: Ok, good to know.  

Thanks.

Comment: When using the same account user credentials and Business Unit when you created your app, do you have permission to access Journey Builder through the UI?

Comment: Indeed I do, Eliot.  It is a little misleading that the AppCenter allows the changing of permissions if indeed they aren't actually able to be changed, but   creating a new App solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Package needs permissions to READ on Interactions.